# how to add terme store list to search sharepoint sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365-developer

I have a Search Center site, with filters of search :
[image: picture 1]

I wanna call my list of TermStore picture 2 , and add it like a suggestion in picture 1.
[image: picture 2]

How can i do it?

Answer (score -1):

I am not very clear on what you are trying to achieve here, but to show a managed metadata column as a filter, you need to map it to a refinable field on the search schema screen. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aatishblogs/2014/02/02/refiners-for-managed-metadata-columns-in-sharepoint-online/) is a guide on how to achieve that.

1. Logon to Microsoft Online Portal (MOP)
2. Go to SharePoint Online
   Administration Center page.
3. On the Left Panel -> Select ‘Search’
4. Click ‘Manage Search Schema’ Search for Existing Managed property
   ‘RefineableString00’ -> Edit the property and set it up as per
   below. -> Click ‘OK‘

[image]

1. Go to the Subsite Search Center site created in Step 2.
2. Type in any keyword to go to the ‘Results.aspx’ page. -> ‘Edit’ that page.
3. Edit the Refinement Panel web Part. -> Click on ‘Choose Refiners…’ button.
4. From the list of ‘Available Refiners’ -> Select ‘RefineableString00’ -> Click ‘Add’ button.
5. Change the ‘Display Name’ for it (Initially it may not show the Sample Values, wait for around 5-10 mins to take effect )
6. Click ‘Ok’ -> Save and Close the Page -> Check-In and Publish the Page

[image]

Comment: Can you provide details on how to do so? Link-only answers are not helpful when the links break, or if they cannot be accessed (due to proxies that some users may be behind).

Comment: i wanna add my term store list , as a filter in my advanced search